# Discrepancy in Query Planning Times for Two Almost Equivalent PostgreSQL Queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I've been working with PostgreSQL and found something puzzling.
I have two similar queries (instead of ANY the exact match can be as well):

```sql
SELECT
    "ColumnA",
    "ColumnB",
    "ColumnC"
FROM 
    "MyTable"
WHERE 
    "ColumnC" = ANY (ARRAY[SomeInteger1, SomeInteger2])
    AND "ColumnB" > '2023-08-23 20:59:59.9999994 +00:00';
```

and

```sql
SELECT
    "ColumnA",
    "ColumnB",
    "ColumnC"
FROM 
    "MyTable"
WHERE 
    "ColumnC" = ANY (ARRAY[SomeInteger1, SomeInteger2])
    AND "ColumnB" > '2023-08-23 20:59:59.9999995 +00:00';
```

Here, "ColumnA", "ColumnB", and "ColumnC" symbolize my actual column names and "SomeInteger1" and "SomeInteger2" are placeholders for two integers.

Both queries yield the same number of rows, but the planning times differ substantially, despite the only difference being the timestamp value. What's more intriguing is that I've noticed there is some kind of "border" timestamp. For timestamp values below this "border", the planning time is significantly slower, whereas for values above it, the planning time is much faster. The integers used in the ANY clause also seem to affect where this "border" is.

Here are the EXPLAIN ANALYZE outputs:

For the first query:

```
Query Plan

Index Scan using "PK_MyTable" on "MyTable"  
(cost=0.57..308.72 rows=260 width=24)  
(actual time=0.029..0.047 rows=5 loops=1)

    Index Condition: ("ColumnC" = ANY ('{SomeInteger1,SomeInteger2}'::bigint[]))
    Filter: ("ColumnB" > '2023-08-23 20:59:59.9999994 +00:00'::timestamp with time zone)

Planning Time: 0.101 ms
Execution Time: 0.063 ms
```

For the second query:

```
Query Plan 

Index Scan using "PK_MyTable" on "MyTable"  
(cost=0.57..308.72 rows=260 width=24)  
(actual time=0.019..0.029 rows=5 loops=1)

    Index Condition: ("ColumnC" = ANY ('{SomeInteger1,SomeInteger2}'::bigint[]))
    Filter: ("ColumnB" > '2023-08-23 20:59:59.9999995 +00:00'::timestamp with time zone)

Planning Time: 3253.013 ms
Execution Time: 0.052 ms
```

Here are the schema of table:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTable" (
    "ColumnC" bigint NOT NULL,
    "ColumnA" bigint NOT NULL,
    "ColumnB" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "AnotherColumn" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "MyTable_ColumnC_ColumnA_UNIQ" ON "MyTable"
USING btree ("ColumnC", "ColumnA");

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "MyTable_ColumnB" ON "MyTable"
USING btree ("ColumnB");
```

PostgreSQL version:

```
SELECT version()

PostgreSQL 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

The execution times are almost identical, but the planning time for the latter query is vastly larger than that of the former. I'm unsure why such a minimal difference in the timestamp value would produce such a pronounced discrepancy in the planning time.

I have already tried running these queries multiple times at different intervals to rule out temporary server load issues. Each time, the same disparity in planning time occurs.

My expectation was that these two similar queries would have similar planning and execution times, given that the only difference between the two is the value for the "ColumnB" date time condition in the WHERE clause - specifically, a second difference in the timestamp.

Additionally, I tried looking into system load, network issues, and possible concurrent system maintenance processes, but didn't find anything conspicuously relating to the issue. Also, no disk I/O bottlenecks were noticed at the time of this query execution.

I was wondering if the timestamp precision or the ANY clause, or any other PostgreSQL specific characteristic, could be playing a role in this disparity. I am seeking guidance on what might be causing this and if there's any inherent PostgreSQL behavior that I'm not aware of.

Any SQL optimization documents or PostgreSQL guidelines are also appreciated to learn more about potential influences on planning time in PostgreSQL.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any index on `ColumnB`?

Comment: Weird! Can you [edit] your question to show your complete table and index definitions? What happens if you do `ANALYZE TABLE MyTable` then repeat these experiments?

Comment: Yes, I have two indexes the first on primary key (ColumnC, ColumnA) and index on ColumnB

Comment: I added schema definitions of table and indexes in question above. `ANALYZE "MyTable"` produces error: `[25006] ERROR: cannot execute ANALYZE during recovery` Tried on all replicas (including primary)

Comment: Then it is highly probable that it's being caused by the index. Can you create a `MyTable2` table with the very same structure and data as in `MyTable`, but without the index? If so, would you see the differences you described?

Comment: Perhaps I might be unable to do so, as this is a production database and it's extremely large. However, I'll consider your hypothesis.

Comment: @EgorBaydarov maybe there is a backup that you can import somewhere. Or maybe it's reproduced at a test db instance as well

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have sub-microsecond precision on its timestamps.  You can specify more precision on input, but it will be rounded and the plan will show that rounded value not the original.  So you don't seem to be using community PostgreSQL.  What are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

Comment: If the data is not confidential, we are waiting for a dump.

Comment: I'm unable to do so. The database is confidential and for security reasons, I have hidden the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are indexes at play here,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "MyTable_ColumnC_ColumnA_UNIQ" ON "MyTable"
USING btree ("ColumnC", "ColumnA");

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "MyTable_ColumnB" ON "MyTable"
USING btree ("ColumnB");
```

It very much seems that you have some indexed data between the two dates you use which cause the discrepancy. Of course, you will need to experimentally check whether this is the case.